# Conditional cell formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, openoffice-calc, autoformatting

Is it possible to autoformat spreadsheet like this

IF A1 = C1 then A1:E1  background should become light gray

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I know how to do it, if anyone cares, you do like @Eric Fortis but:

1. formula should be `=$A1=$A3`
2. applies to range `=$A1`
3. copy cell A1
4. select area where you want to do formatting
5. home tab, click on paste dropdown menu
6. choose special paste
7. choose only pasting formats

Comment: oops I meant post it as different question instead of answer

Comment: @EricFortis I know what you meant, but I know how to do it, so I don't need help anymore :)

Comment: Cool, the answer might help others and to close this question, you can post it and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Note the yellow highlights,

1. Conditional Formating
2. Formula `=$A$1=$A$3`
3. Color Background
4. Applies to range `=$A$1:$E$1`

Comment: I made mistake in my question, it should be A1=C1, but anyway, when i made this conditional it works only for 1 row, I want that it would work for entire document, like if A1=C1 then change colour A1:E1, if A2=C2 then change colour A2:E2 and etc.

Comment: I suggest you posting it as a separate answer. Maybe someone gets interested